# Making Mootools more into Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I'm currently a Mootools beginner (started leanrning today). And I come from jQuery. I learned about `Element.Implement`.

I'm trying to add the .ready function from jquery to mootools.

Jquery .ready example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Do stuff onload
});
```

I'm attempting to do this with mootools like this:

```
Element.implement({
ready: function(a){
       return this.addEvent('domready', a)
    }
});
```

But as I said. I'm a mootools beginner and I can't debug this.

I'm doing this because I like all the jquery functions. And Im used to the names of them. But I like that mootools has some advantages over jquery. And I know I could just use both. But thats to complicated

Comment: What do you need from MooTools that jQuery doesn't have? Maybe you can make a compromise.

Comment: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/DOMReady

Comment: Hey Shawn, I have experience with both jQuery and mooTools. I understand the frustration of learning new naming conventions when going to a new language but I think you will be better served learning the moo way as well as retaining the jQuery code that you are used to. $(document).ready(func) is window.addEvent('domready',func). Thats all, your file would be jQuery to Mootools "compatibility" file would be HUGE if you were to map all functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
function domready(domreadycode){
    window.addEvent('domready', domreadycode);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
domready(function(){
    //code when document is ready
});
```

example:http://jsfiddle.net/U3XRM/